# tkinter python - menu button doesnt work with a loop

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I have a project with a problem that I recreated in this small code

```
from tkinter import *
    
top = Tk()
    
mb=  Menubutton ( top, text="condiments", relief=RAISED )
mb.grid()
mb.menu =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"] =  mb.menu

for dressing in ['ketchup','mayo']:
    mb.menu.add_command( label=dressing , command=lambda:print(dressing))

mb.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

so in this example, no matter what I choose in the menu - it prints "mayo" because the last dressing in the loop is mayo and the loop created the menu.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()
    
mb=Menubutton(top,text="condiments",relief=RAISED)
mb.grid()
mb.menu=Menu(mb,tearoff=0)
mb["menu"]=mb.menu

for dressing in ['ketchup','mayo']:
    mb.menu.add_command(label=dressing,command=lambda d=dressing:print(d))

mb.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Adding `d=dressing` stores the current value of `dressing` in a variable `d` which is sent to the `print` statement.

> it prints "mayo" because the last dressing in the loop is mayo

That's the precise reason, when the `lambda` function was executed later, it took the last assigned value of `dressing` which in your case happens to be `mayo` and not the value that it had at the time of assignment.